# FDT: How to edit package arguments? // useLegacyAOT no //Adobe AIR

Tags: air, adobe, fdt

I am using FDT to develop mobile AIR applications.

I have read about the improvement in compile time, which is available in the new Air SDK 4.0 - you just have to use **-useLegacyAOT no** in your package command.

Can I somehow edit the package arguments, which FDT uses, or will I have to do packaging on command line?

Thx for helping, Thomas Kagerer

Comment: A lot of people are having issues getting it to work when not using command line to compile. I've seen that it must be placed behind "provisioning-profile" to work, though I wasn't able to get that to work, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

There exists a workaround described here: http://bugs.powerflasher.com/jira/browse/FDT-3295